# google places api works in html but not in cshtml

Tags: visual-studio, google-maps, asp.net-core

I am trying to build a .net core project that will use the google places api to autocomplete an address.  To test the process I copied the demo code from google and put it in the .net core template generated by visual studio 2017.  The autocomplete doesn't work, but if I change the .cshtml to .html and navigate to it manually it works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Place Autocomplete Address Form</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }
    /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500">
  <style>
    #locationField, #controls {
      position: relative;
      width: 480px;
    }

    #autocomplete {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 99%;
    }

    .label {
      text-align: right;
      font-weight: bold;
      width: 100px;
      color: #303030;
    }

    #address {
      border: 1px solid #000090;
      background-color: #f0f0ff;
      width: 480px;
      padding-right: 2px;
    }

      #address td {
        font-size: 10pt;
      }

    .field {
      width: 99%;
    }

    .slimField {
      width: 80px;
    }

    .wideField {
      width: 200px;
    }

    #locationField {
      height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />

  <div id="locationField">
    <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address"
           onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"></input>
  </div>

  <table id="address">
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Street address</td>
      <td class="slimField">
        <input class="field" id="street_number"
               disabled="true"></input>
      </td>
      <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
        <input class="field" id="route"
               disabled="true"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">City</td>
      <!-- Note: Selection of address components in this example is typical.
           You may need to adjust it for the locations relevant to your app. See
           https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform
      -->
      <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
        <input class="field" id="locality"
               disabled="true"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">State</td>
      <td class="slimField">
        <input class="field"
               id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true"></input>
      </td>
      <td class="label">Zip code</td>
      <td class="wideField">
        <input class="field" id="postal_code"
               disabled="true"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label">Country</td>
      <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
        <input class="field"
               id="country" disabled="true"></input>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script>
    // This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
    // of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

    // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
    // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
    // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

    var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
      street_number: 'short_name',
      route: 'long_name',
      locality: 'long_name',
      administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
      country: 'long_name',
      postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initAutocomplete() {
      // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
      // location types.
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        (document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        { types: ['geocode'] });

      // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
      // fields in the form.
      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
    }

    function fillInAddress() {
      // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(component).value = '';
        document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
      }

      // Get each component of the address from the place details
      // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
      for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
        var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
        if (componentForm[addressType]) {
          var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
          document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
        }
      }
    }


  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPIKeythat works in html&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
          async defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was that the wrong API was activated on google. I enabled it in google and it works in the project now. I have no idea why it worked in the plain html.